# Textbox not displaying correctly

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Based off this VB code I'm getting everything to create correctly within my SQL database but instead of the Food_ID displaying in the txtfoodid it's popping up in a message box (I think it's because of the Try/Catch).

```
 Dim con As New OleDbConnection(DBcon)
    Try
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
        Dim command As New OleDbCommand("Insert into Donation (Donor_ID) VALUES ( " & txtDonNum.Text & "); Select @@Identity;")

        con.Open()
        command.Connection = con
        dr = command.ExecuteReader
        Dim Donation_ID As String = ""
        If dr.Read() Then
            Donation_ID = dr(0).ToString
            Dim food As New OleDbCommand("Insert into Food_Donation (Date_Received, Donation_ID) Values ( '" & maskedreceived.Text & "', " & Donation_ID & "); Select @@Identity")
            food.Connection = con
            dr = food.ExecuteReader()
            'food.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If
        Dim Food_ID As String
        If dr.Read() Then
            Food_ID = dr(0).ToString
            txtfoodid.Text = dr("Food_ID").ToString
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try

    MessageBox.Show("Food_ID has been made.")

End Sub
```

I've tried multiple ways of getting it to display but nothing's worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing column txtfoodid.Text = dr("Food_ID").ToString but your Select statement returns only @@Identity.

There is no Food_ID column returned from that reader. Either create a new Select query with it's own reader OR modify your second statement to return the Food_ID column.

Additionally your code here is incredibly susceptible to SQL injection types of attacks and would recommend reading [Stop Sql Injection Attacks Before They Stop You](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163917.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Pepto is mostly right.  The only thing is, you have the information you need.  Basically, just change this line

```
txtfoodid.Text = dr("Food_ID").ToString
```

to

```
txtfoodid.Text = Food_ID
```

and you will be good to go.  You are trying to read the Food_ID out of the DataReader when you already got it and assigned it to the variable Food_ID.